# Alternative for recursion

Tags: c++

I write a C++ calculator that can interpret function definitions as well as normal expressions. When calculating recursive functions, it works like this,

for example:
input:`f(1)＝1;f(2)＝1;f(x)＝f(x-1)+f(x-2);f(400)`

first it stores the definition of `f`, and when asked for `f(400)`, it substitutes 400 for `x` in the definition, and calculates that.

This works fine for 400 or even 4000, but apparently it is recursive so that if the number is big enough the stack will eventually be used up.

I wonder if there is a way to improve the algorithm and avoid this problem?
(I've thought about creating new threads or process, or diving the calculation so when asked for 10000, it first calculates 2000, then 4000, ..., and finally 10000, but that doesn't seem to be so convenient.)

p.s.Previously calculated values are stored.

Comment: Read about tail call optimization. Also, try to memorize previous results to remove redundant calls.

Comment: 1. Recursion can always be transformed into iteration + maintaining your own stack (which will oftentimes take up much less space than the call stack, for the same problem). 2. If you pay close attention to *this* problem, you don't even need the stack, because computing `f(n-2)` is implicated in computing `f(n-1)`.

Comment: Not sure if the calculation could be done in parallel. f(n) depends on f(n-1). The calculation should be done sequentially. The problem is not only the size of the stack. Please, note that, for example, f(100) is called/calculated twice: one for f(101) and the other for f(102). That's why the recursive solution for this particular problem would be slow.

Comment: Note that, for this particular problem you can do it in constant time and constant memory because there’s a closed-form solution for the nth Fibonacci number. But that doesn’t really address the issue with recursion in the calculator.

Comment: @Stephen I'm sorry that I forgot to mention I've used that technique.

Comment: Your call stack will always take up less space than the memoization area will at the end of the program (because every call gets memoized, so every time something’s in the call stack the result will be put in the memoization area). If space is an issue, then memoizing doesn’t actually help. It just saves time.

Comment: If you are using a data structure like vector for memorization, you are not going to use any stack memory as vector use heap memory.

Comment: @JohnAo Unlike when I wrote my comment, it seems many other gave you the advice I had in my mind. In general, I think using recursion is inevitable as you plan to implement any arbitrary and valid recursive calculation. Thus, if needed, use a system call to increase the stack size. The problem I could see is duplicated computation. Before calculating f(n), look up the table. After calculating f(n) if needed, update the table with f(n).

Answer (score 1):

This is a textbook use case for [Memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).  First, note that f(x) needs f(x-1), which implies it also needs f(x-1-1) which is the same as f(x-2) which f(x) also needs.  So you can save a lot of redundant computation by storing a "cache" of previous calculations and looking there before recursing.

Comment: Except memoization itself doesn't actually solve the problem of running out of stack space.

Comment: @ZalmanStern: Not explicitly and directly, but once you have memoization the stack problem is easy to solve (if it still exists, which it may not because memoization itself does actually reduce the number of recursive calls).

Comment: @JohnZwinck While it reduces the number of calculations which must be performed, how does that change the depth of the recursion?

Comment: This is a good enough answer for the question at hand. There's no possible way the asker could run out of stack space with his current formulation of the problem. His code would take centuries to run long before he used 0.1% of stack space.

Answer (score 1):

If one is implementing a language of sufficient power, executing certain programs in that language will require an arbitrary amount of stack space. Memoization (or dynamic programing) can optimize the amount of stack space for specific cases, but they cannot bound the stack used in general. Similarly for tail recursion as not all functions will be tail recursive. (Though in the same fashion that one can transform recursion into iteration plus a stack, one can transform the program into continuation passing form, which one might consider a generalization of tail recursion.)

As such, if implementing an interpreter for e.g. a pushdown automata, and one wants to handle large problems, one generally implements the stack as an internal data structure in the interpreter. There are a few ways in which this improves things. First the entries on the stack can be smaller than a function call stack frame. Second, the stack can be implemented as a linked list (a "threaded stack" though it is a completely different meaning that that of "thread" as a unit of execution in concurrent programming). Third, when the stack does run out of space, one can handle it in a very clean fashion, which is fairly difficult to do with running out of call stack in most compiled programming languages. (Even identifying stack overflow errors is somewhat tedious in certain environments. Learning to design for bounded recursion early on is a good skill. Doubly so in high reliability or high security applications. Recursive algorithms are often avoided entirely in low-level embedded systems.)

All that said, just using the implementation language's call stack is quite common as it is easier and provides a comfortable economy of mechanism. One can increase the stack limit in most operating systems and setting it to e.g. 16MB may be enough for all practical problems one wishes to handle. See e.g. the `limit` command in shells on UNIX like systems.

Beyond this, high quality implementations of a particular language will use techniques such as memoization, tail recursion, symbolic simplification, etc. to greatly reduce the resources used by a given program. But there will still be programs which defy such optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since the question is tagged [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), why not consider [`std::stack`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack)? This can well avoid using the program's call stack.

```
std::stack<myfunction> mycallstack;
mycallstack.push( /* first function */ );
while (!mycallstack.empty()) {
    /* function */ = mycallstack.pop();
    if ( /* whatever */ ){
        mycallstack.push( /* recursing function call */ );
    }
}
```

You can even mix it with [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple), which I'm not quite familiar with.

Comment: But how can the calculator turn a recursive function definition into DP? The question isn’t about solving the Fibonacci problem in particular (if it were, the correct answer would be to use the closed-form solution).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to transform your whole expression in "reverse polish notation".
So you can avoid all the recursion-calls.

Tokenize your expression and bring the necessary tokens in RPN order -> calculate in O(n) in a simple for-loop.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation

**Idea for transforming:**

You analyse your recursion expression and then transform it
to an infix-notation. It seems not that hard for *simple scenarios*.
This transformation (no calculation) has to be done non-recursive.

If you have it transformed to infix notation, you can easy transform it to 
RPN and solve it fast and without recursion.

```
**n! - function - example**

#recursive expression
f(1)=1
f(n)=f(n−1) * n

#build substitution-lookups (example for n=4)
f(4)       = f(4−1) * 4
f(4−1)     = f(4−1-1) * (4-1)
f(4−1-1)   = f(4−1-1-1) * (4−1-1)
f(4−1-1-1) = 1

#build infix-notation with help of the lookups
f(4−1) * 4
(f(4−1-1) * (4-1)) * 4
((f(4−1-1-1) * (4−1-1)) * (4-1)) * 4
(((1) * (4−1-1)) * (4-1)) * 4
((1 * (4−1-1)) * (4-1)) * 4

**fibonacci - function - example (simplified) **

#recursive expression
f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2)
f(1) = 1
f(2) = 1

#modify it a little bit
f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-1-1)
f(1) = 1
f(2) = 1

#build substitution-lookups (example for n=6)
f(6)          = f(6-1) + f(6-1-1)
f(6-1)        = f(6-1-1) + f(6-1-1-1)
f(6-1-1)      = f(6-1-1-1) + f(6-1-1-1-1)
f(6-1-1-1)    = f(6-1-1-1-1) + f(6-1-1-1-1-1)
f(6-1-1-1-1)  = 1
f(6-1-1-1-1-1)= 1

#build infix-notation with help of the lookups
f(6-1) + f(6-1-1)
(f(6-1-1) + f(6-1-1-1)) + (f(6-1-1-1) + f(6-1-1-1-1))
((f(6-1-1-1) + f(6-1-1-1-1)) + (f(6-1-1-1-1) + f(6-1-1-1-1-1))) + ((f(6-1-1-1-1) + f(6-1-1-1-1-1)) + (1))
(((f(6-1-1-1-1) + f(6-1-1-1-1-1)) + 1) + (1 + 1)) + ((1 + 1) + (1))
(((1 + 1) + 1) + (1 + 1)) + ((1 + 1) + (1))
```

Comment: RPN is good for solving expressions iteratively (without the necessity to consider precedences or parentheses). For me, it's not clear how this applies to _recursive functions_. May be, you could elaborate. (A small code sample would be very appreciated...)

Comment: Added an example to my answer, but maybe you are right and it is not the right "tool" for this type of problem.